# Why I can't scrape the data inside of <ul> tag

Tags: html, xpath

I am trying to scrape reviews data on the booking.com that is inside of `<ul>` tag with the `class="review_list"`. There are 10 reviews, each of them is inside of `<li>`with the `class="review_list_new_item_block"`.

[image]

And here is the picture of data inside of the first `<li>`tag:

[image]

But I noticed that I can't scrape most of the data inside of this `<ul>` and `<li>`tags, although I always use the same logic for the xpaths. I tried for example following xpaths to scrape `title, text, language, review date` and `stay date`:

```
title = response.xpath('//h3[@class="c-review-block__title"]/text()').extract()
#title = response.xpath('//div[@class="c-review-block__row"]//h3/text()')

text = response.xpath('//span[@class="c-review__prefix c-review__prefix--color-green"]/span[2]/text()').extract()

lang = response.xpath('//span[@class="c-review__prefix c-review__prefix--color-green"]/span[2]/@lang').extract()

reviewdate = response.xpath('//span[@class="c-review-block__date"]/text()').extract()

staydate = response.xpath('//div[@class="c-review-block__room-info__name"]/div/span/text()').extract()
```

Only xpaths for these two items worked:

```
author = response.xpath('//span[@class="bui-avatar-block__title"]/text()').extract()
authorcountry = response.xpath('//span[@class="bui-avatar-block__subtitle"]/text()').extract()
```

Do you have any suggestions? Is it the issue in the way I am using the xpaths or does booking.com have any restrictions in this place of HTML-Code? Thank you in advance!

My script:

```py
import scrapy

class BookingSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'booking-spider'
    allowed_domains = ['booking.com']
    # start with the page of all countries
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.booking.com/country.de.html?aid=356980;label=gog235jc-1DCAIoLDgcSAdYA2gsiAEBmAEHuAEHyAEP2AED6AEB-AECiAIBqAIDuAK7q7DyBcACAQ;sid=8de61678ac61d10a89c13a3941fd3dcd'
    ]

    # get country page
    def parse(self, response):

        for countryurl in response.xpath('normalize-space(//a[contains(text(),"Schweiz")]/@href)'):
            url = response.urljoin(countryurl.extract())
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_country)

    # get page of all hotels in a country
    def parse_country(self, response):

        for hotelsurl in response.xpath('normalize-space(//a[@class="bui-button bui-button--secondary"]/@href)'):
            url = response.urljoin(hotelsurl.extract())
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_allhotels)

    # get page of one hotel
    def parse_allhotels(self, response):

        for hotelurl in response.xpath('normalize-space(//a[@class="hotel_name_link url"]/@href)'):
            url = response.urljoin(hotelurl.extract())
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_hotelpage)

        next_page = response.xpath('//a[contains(@class,"paging-next") and contains(@title,"Nächste Seite")]/@href')
        if next_page:
            url = response.urljoin(next_page[0].extract())
            yield scrapy.Request(url, self.parse_allhotels)

    # get review page of this hotel
    def parse_hotelpage(self, response):

        reviewsurl = response.xpath('//a[@class="hp_nav_reviews_link toggle_review track_review_link_zh"]/@href')
        url = response.urljoin(reviewsurl[0].extract())
        new_url = url.replace('blockdisplay4', 'tab-reviews')
        yield scrapy.Request(new_url, callback=self.parse_reviews, dont_filter=True)

    # parse its reviews
    def parse_reviews(self, response):

        author = response.xpath('//span[@class="bui-avatar-block__title"]/text()').extract()
        authorcountry = response.xpath('//span[@class="bui-avatar-block__subtitle"]/text()').extract()

        title = response.xpath('//div[@class="c-review-block"]//div[@class="c-review-block__row"]//h3/text()').extract()
        print(title)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below xpaths.

title:

```
//div[@class='c-review-block']//div[@class="c-review-block__row"]//h3/text()
```

text (includes both great and poor text)

```
//div[@class='c-review-block']//div[@class='c-review-block__row'][3]//text()
```

review date

```
//div[@class='c-review-block']//div[@class='c-review-block__row']//span[@class="c-review-block__date"]/text()
```

stay date:

```
//div[@class='c-review-block']//div[@class='c-review-block__room-info']//span[@class="c-review-block__date"]/text()
```

subtitle:

```
//div[@class='c-review-block']//span[@class="bui-avatar-block__subtitle"]/text()
```

You have to get the `review` nodes by using `//div[@class='c-review-block']` and then iterate through all the nodes to get the details. If you are iterating through each review then you just have to replace `//div[@class='c-review-block']` with `.` in the so that the xpath are in the `review` contenxt.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But I still get an empty list with these xpaths ...

Comment: Are you sure the script is waiting enough time to load these elements? I checked the xpaths and they all are working.  Hope you are clicking on the `Guest Reviews` before getting the response.

Comment: How can script wait longer? The script is clicking on the reviews button on the webpage, and some of data I can scrape, for example reviewer name and reviewer country.

Comment: Are you using selenium to click rebiews button?

Comment: I will add my script to the question.

Comment: Not sure how you are clicking on the reviews button in your script. Can you please share the direct link to the page where you are trying to get the response.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210547/discussion-between-alise-and-supputuri).